# Copy Folder To A Range Of Computers On LAN

Tags: powershell

I want to copy a folder to a range of computers on my LAN.  Here is what I have so far:

```psh
$Computers = "Get-Content C:\Scripts\computers.txt"

$Source = "C:\Install\9_10_00_08HotFix_201504140001"
$Destination = "\\192.168.6.$\c$\Install"

ForEach-Object {
  Copy-Item -Path $Source -Recurse -Destination $Destination -Verbose -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work?  What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what your actual problem is, but it's probably that you misplaced the first double quote in the `Get-Content` statement, that you can't define a variable destination like you do, and that you don't do anything with what you (try to) read from `computers.txt`.

Change this:

```psh
$Computers = "Get-Content C:\Scripts\computers.txt"

$Source = "C:\Install\9_10_00_08HotFix_201504140001"
$Destination = "\\192.168.6.$\c$\Install"

ForEach-Object {
  Copy-Item -Path $Source -Recurse -Destination $Destination -Verbose -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

into this:

```psh
$Computers = Get-Content "C:\Scripts\computers.txt"

$Source = "C:\Install\9_10_00_08HotFix_201504140001"

$Computers | ForEach-Object {
  Copy-Item -Path $Source -Recurse -Destination "\\192.168.6.$_\c$\Install" -Verbose -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

and your code should work.

Comment: I changed it to what you specified and ran the script and got Copy-Item : The network path was not found
At C:\Install\CopyToNetwork.ps1:6 char:3
+   Copy-Item -Path $Source -Recurse -Destination "\\192.168.6.$_\c$\In ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Comment: @alexolynyk Check the value of `$_` and verify that the host with that IP address is actually running, that administrative shares are enabled, that access to shares is not blocked by the Windows-Firewall, and that your account has permission to access administrative shares on that host.